# Sensitivity of depth, infrared and RGB images

Tags: computer-vision

I wonder to which outer influences the three kinds of images listed in the title (depth, infrared, RGB) are especially sensitive to.

For example and especially, which of them is sensitive to illumination changes (and why)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB images would be sensitive to illumination changes, infrared would not be affected as they come from a heat sensor, and for depth images it depends how you are computing depth

Comment: thanks, I guess there is not much more to say to this question... ;-)